# Change site name from 'Programmers' to 'Programming'

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

It would make 1000% more sense given the type of discussions people want to see here.

Comment: If you wish to talk about changing the site scope or title or any of those other things to fit the perspective you appear to have, I humbly suggest you read the annals of meta.p.se first, there has been **much** debate through here about the topic in the past; it was finally put to bed around the end of last year after a great deal of tumult on the topic, the reasons for such tumult will become clear if you start reading through.

Comment: @JimmyHoffa - Honestly I'm removing my account from SE.Programmers.  This exchange site is one that values form more than function. As a result it is not a useful resource to me or enjoyable to participate in.  I may be the only one that feels this way, but by reading what gets closed and the discussions in meta.programmers on the topic Im clearly not alone on this.